# Find what files a program is using

Tags: windows-xp, export

I have a piece of software that contains data I would like to move to another computer. The problem is the program does not provide any way to export this data. Does any software exist that will let you know what files a program is using? I know there are programs that given a file, will tell you what program is using it but I'm looking for the opposite.

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: The OS is Windows XP.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who commented. I haven't heard of the majority of the progress but they look pretty great. This thread has just been bookmarked ;) I'd upvote your answers but I'm 4 points away :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx)'s handle viewer (`View->Lower Pane View->Handles`) to see all of the files a process has open on a Windows machine.

Answer (score 3):

As another answer suggests process explorer will show you currently open file handles for a process.  (It is absolutely one of the best tools out there.)

If that is not enough,  [Process *Monitor*](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) will show you a complete log of all file and registry operations that a process performs.   That might help if you find you've missed something (like a registry key) after moving it.

It sounds like the software you are using is not very friendly.   Let the developer know that you will be looking at alternatives if they won't provide an export feature.

Comment: +1 for procmon, too bad that it can be hard to sift through the log since it gathers a ton of data

Answer (score 3):

**[Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/)** is very similar to Process Explorer and is also free, but this one is open-source. It equally let you find which files are being used by a process.

Answer (score 1):

Process Explorer is good, but it only shows you what is currently running, a library might just be used for initialization and then discarded or only used during some obscure time.  [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) might be what you're after.